# Upload a video file in Akamai netstorage using PHP

Tags: php, upload, akamai

I started working on uploading a file to akamai netstorage using PHP and referred few API's in GitHub. I couldn't upload a video file. Though i can create and write contents in them.

```
<?php
 require 'Akamai.php';
 $service = new Akamai_Netstorage_Service('******.akamaihd.net');
 $service->authorize('key','keyname','version');
 $service->upload('/dir-name/test/test.txt','sample text');
 ?>
```

I referred this [API](https://github.com/raben/Akamai). I also referred few others but couldn't get the right way to upload a video/image file. The code which i wrote above is working perfectly. Now i need to upload a video file instead of writing contents to a text file.

Comment: Has  the directory to which you are uploading already been created? Also try losing the first `/` i.e.  change the last line to `$service->upload('dir-name/test/test.txt','sample text');`

Comment: The code which i wrote above is working perfectly. Now i need to upload a video file instead of writing contents to a text file

Answer (score 0):

There is a more modern library for Akamai's NetStorage, which is built as a plugin for [FlySystem](http://flysystem.thephpleague.com), the [akamai-open/netstorage](https://github.com/akamai-open/netstorage-php).

Once you have it installed, you need to setup the authentication and the HTTP client (based on [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle)):

```
$signer = new \Akamai\NetStorage\Authentication();
$signer->setKey($key, $keyName);

$handler = new \Akamai\NetStorage\Handler\Authentication();
$handler->setSigner($signer);

$stack = \GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack::create();
$stack->push($handler, 'netstorage-handler');

$client = new \Akamai\Open\EdgeGrid\Client([
    'base_uri' => $host,
    'handler' => $stack
]);

$adapter = new \Akamai\NetStorage\FileStoreAdapter($client, $cpCode);
```

And then you can create the filesystem object, and upload the file:

```
$fs = new \League\Flysystem\Filesystem($adapter);

// Upload a file:
// cpCode, action, content signature, and request signature is added transparently
// Additionally, all required sub-directories are created transparently
$fs->write('/path/to/write/file/to', $fileContents);
```

However, because you're uploading a video file I would suggest you use a stream rather than reading the contents in to memory. To do this, you use `writeStream()` instead:

```
$fs = new \League\Flysystem\Filesystem($adapter);
$stream = fopen('/path/to/local/file', 'r+');
$fs->writeStream('/path/to/write/file/to', $stream);
```